# Topologies generated by the metric $d(x,y)=|f(x)-f(y)|$ for $f$ increasing function and euclidean metric are equivalent

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, continuity, metric-spaces

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ an strictly increasing function. Then $d(x,y)=|f(x)-f(y)|$ is a metric, no problem proving this.Then the topologt generated $d$ and  the topology generated by euclidean metric $d_{E}$ are equivalent. To prove this last statement I need to prove the following two things:

(1) For every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and each $\epsilon > 0$ there is some $\delta > 0$ such we have the contention $B_{d}(x, \delta) \subseteq B_{d_{E}}(x, \epsilon)$.

(2) For every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and each $\epsilon>0$ there is some $\delta >0$ such we have the contention $B_{d_{E}}(x, \delta) \subseteq B_{d}(x, \epsilon)$.

I prove (2) taking $y \in B_{d_{E}}(x, \delta)$, then $d_{E}(x,y)=|x-y| < \delta$ and by the continuity of $f$ we have $d(x,y)=|f(x)-f(y)| < \epsilon$. This last inequality means $y \in B_{d}(x, \epsilon)$. So $B_{d_{E}}(x, \delta) \subseteq B_{d}(x, \epsilon)$.

Proving (1) seems a lot harder or at least since I dont see how to proceed, I have been thinking to  prove $f^{-1}$ exist and this inverse function is continuous but Im not sure. Any help to finish this proof will be apreciated.

Comment: "Crescent function"? The correct English there is "increasing". Also, a/an depends on the first sound in the next word; with the next word "strictly" starting with a consonant sound, that should be "a".

Answer (score 2):

There's a catch here: a strictly increasing function need not be continuous. For example, $f(x)=\begin{cases}x+1&x>0\\0&x=0\\x-1&x<0\end{cases}$ is not continuous at zero, and the resulting metric $d(x,y)=f(|x-y|)$ does not induce the usual topology. The ball of radius $\frac12$ centered at zero contains only the point $0$, so the single-element set $\{0\}$ is open in this topology (and, of course, not in the usual topology).

For this to be true, we need the additional hypothesis that $f$ is continuous.

Yes, showing that $f^{-1}$ exists and is continuous (for continuous $f$) is a good way to go. The Intermediate Value Theorem may be helpful here.

Comment: Thanks! Any hint to prove $f^-1$ exist and is continuous will be aprecciated. @jmerry

Comment: The Intermediate Value Theorem is my hint for the existence of the inverse. Well, not an inverse defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$. The range of $f$, after all, can be some smaller interval. (Example: $f(x)=\arctan x$, with range $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$)

Comment: Still see foggy the proof of $f^{-1$ is continuous on some intervals  and how IVT helps proving this :( @jmerry

Comment: I think we only need $f$ to be continuous at $0$.

Comment: Mmm, I dont see any thing with Intermediate Value theorem and Ihave been thinking that for a little more than 3 hours. All I have is that as $f$ is continuous, then for  every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and every $\epsilon > 0$ we that for the open set $B_{d_{E}}(f(x), \epsilon)$ there is an open set $B_{d}(x, \delta)$ proving what we want, isnt right? @jmerry

Comment: Im supposed to find a $\delta>0$ working but how can I find it? @jmerry

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: On second thought - no, we need continuity everywhere. The distance we're using is the difference of $f$, not $f$ of the difference.

Comment: @Cos: The $\delta$ you need: the maximum of $f(x+\epsilon)-f(x)$ and $f(x)-f(x-\epsilon)$. Oddly enough, we don't need the continuity of $f$ for part (1).